# cannot get the size of a string in C++ visual studio

Tags: c++, sfml

I wrote a simple program to delete a letter in a string with backspace to use while typing. It's supposed to get the length of the string each time and delete the last character but I can't get function `.length();` to work in my program which I saw it used in stackoverflow by another person.

```
Event eventInput;
string stringLength;
String userInput;
Text userText;
while (window.pollEvent(eventInput))
{
    if (eventInput.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Backspace))
        {
            stringLength = userInput.length();
            userInput.erase(1, 1);
        }
        userInput += eventInput.text.unicode;
        userText.setString(userInput);
    }
}
```

It says `sf::String` has no member length

Comment: `string` & `String` ? ... Mixing types like that and not even using the namespace prefix is an awful idea. Anyway according to the [sfml doc](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1String.php) `sf::String` doesn't have a `length()` function, the equivalent is `sf::String::getSize`

Comment: @George `stringLength` should not be any sort of string. It should be an integer.

Comment: They're seem to be other errors as well. For instance the inner if statement should clearly be an if else statement. It not clear that the `stringLength` variable is being used for anything in any case. It could probably be deleted.

Comment: @john Me not reading the name :/ Though it's worying if that code compiles, suggests they've included `using namespace std;` & `using namespace sf;`.

Comment: @George Doesn't compile, the OP included a compiler error message

Comment: for some reason none of my inputs show up on screen

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `std::string` has a length member function.  `sf::String`, which is what `userInput` is, does not.  It has a [`getSize`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1String.php#ae7aff54e178f5d3e399953adff5cad20) member function that you should use instead.

Comment: for some reason I can't get the text to display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you (and your code) are mixing up two different types of string. `String` and `string` are not the same. It seems you want the SFML string class which is called `String`. And the method to get the length of an SFML string is called [`getSize`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1String.php#ae7aff54e178f5d3e399953adff5cad20) not `length`.

You would avoid some of this confusion if you did not add `using namespace sf;` and `using namespace std;` to your code.

Another error in your code is the handling of backspace. Your code deletes a characters when it detects a backspace but then adds it back again. This is because your code has an `if` statement when it should have an `if ... else` statement. Like this

```
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Backspace))
{
    stringLength = userInput.length();
    userInput.erase(1, 1);
}
else
{
    userInput += eventInput.text.unicode;
    userText.setString(userInput);
}
```

One of the things you will learn is to look at your code and see what it really says.

Comment: for some reason my code is not is working even after the syntax was fixed as the letters aren't deleted and backpase appears as a square. thevonly efective thing to me was deleting the first character of a string and having one square